# Replace single quotes with double quotes in tags only! Using ColdFusion regex

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I only see PHP solutions to this problem.

Basically I need to go from:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING='2'><P ALIGN='LEFT'><FONT FACE='Verdana' style='font-size:10' COLOR='#0B333C'>My name's Mark</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

to this:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10" COLOR="#0B333C">My name's Mark</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

Using ReReplaceNoCase but ... yup you guessed it .. I suck at regular expressions! :)

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a regex, you can do what you need in this case by letting CF do the work for you, via XML parsing libraries:

```
<cfsavecontent variable = "origStr">
    <cfoutput>
        <TEXTFORMAT LEADING='2'><P ALIGN='LEFT'><FONT FACE='Verdana' style='font-size:10' COLOR='##0B333C'>My name's Mark</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset xmlString = ToString(xmlParse(origStr))>

<cfdump var="#xmlString#">
```

Which will get back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT COLOR="#0B333C" FACE="Verdana" style="font-size:10">My name's Mark</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

If that leading `<?xml...>` annoys you, you can cut that part off:

```
<cfdump var="#Right(xmlString, Len(xmlString) - 40)#">
```

Comment: Thanks Jake that works a **treat**!! The only issue I am having is that I am actually trying to validate MathML data which has it's own DTD and the validation pukes on the m:math tag. So I have to add the name-space for the MathML on the opening tag (xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML") and this is way to much modification for my liking. Oh well I'll work something out!! Thanks a bunch!!